# How to display the matched words of an Algolia search query?

Tags: javascript, search, algolia

I'm using Algolia's [algoliasearch-client-js](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js) and [autocomplete.js](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js) to power searches on my website. That works.

But I also want to include the excerpt/snippet of the text with which the search query matches. How to do that?

---

My current code is:

```
autocomplete('#search-input', { hint: true, autoselect: true }, [
{
    source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, { hitsPerPage: 7 }),
    displayKey: 'title',
    templates: {
        footer: '<span class="search-foot">Powered by <a href="https://www.algolia.com/" target="_blank" title="Algolia - Hosted cloud search as a service"><img src="/static/assets/algolia-logo.png" width="47" height="15"></a></span>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          return '<div class="search-lang">' + 
              suggestion._highlightResult.platform.value + 
              '</div>' + 
              suggestion._highlightResult.title.value;
        }
    }
}
]).on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
  window.location.href = suggestion.url;
});
```

---

To highlight the excerpt that caused the query to match with a record, their [FAQ](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/searching/what-is-attributes-to-snippet-how-does-it-work) says:

> The AttributesToSnippet setting is a way to shorten ("snippet") your
>   long chunks of text to display them in the search results. Just think
>   about the small pieces of text displayed below a Google result: it's
>   built from a subset of the sentences of the page content, includes
>   your matching keywords, and avoid flooding the search results page. 
>   For example, if you limit the number of words of the "description"
>   attribute to 10, the "_snippetResult.description.value" attribute of
>   the JSON answer will only contain the 10 best words of this
>   description.

There's no example of `AttributesToSnippet`, however. On their [Github documentation](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js) I find a bit more info:

> attributesToHighlight
>
> - scope: settings, search
> - type: array of strings
> - default: null
>
> Default list of attributes to highlight. If set to null, all indexed
>   attributes are highlighted.
>
> A string that contains the list of attributes you want to highlight
>   according to the query. Attributes are separated by commas. You can
>   also use a string array encoding (for example ["name","address"]). If
>   an attribute has no match for the query, the raw value is returned. By
>   default, all indexed attributes are highlighted (as long as they are
>   strings). You can use * if you want to highlight all attributes.

I'm struggling with translating their abstract, scattered information into a coherent piece of code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your current piece of code should already highlight matching words with `suggestion._highlightResult.title.value`. If you inspect element a word that should have matched, you should see `<em>` tags around the matching word.

Comment: `attributesToSnippet` works exactly the same way as `attributesToHighlight`, except you'd use `_snippetResult` instead of `_highlightResult` in your template, but for titles, you probably don't need that.

Comment: @Jerska Thanks for commenting. That's true, `_highlightResult.title.value` returns me the title of the content that matches with the search query. But it doesn't show me which part of the content caused that title to pop up.

Comment: @Jerska (2nd comment). Accessing `_snippetResult` in my current code gives an 'undefined' error message. I already tried that (and a lot of other things); that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: What attributes did you specify in your `attributesToIndex` ?

Comment: @Jerska None. I use the autocomplete.js wrapper and didn't need to specify the `attributesToIndex` from algoliasearch-client-js when initialising. Perhaps I do need now, but `attributesToIndex` is not an [option of autocomplete](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#options).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the problem myself, due to finding a setting in Algolia's dashboard by pure luck. To make the returned search results return the snippet too, I did two things:

**1)**. There's an option in Algolia's dashboard that's named 'Attributes to snippet', which you can find in the 'Display' tab of the particular index that you're searching with.

In my case, I set that option to the record attribute that I wanted to highlight in my search queries like this:

[image: Image of Algolia settings]

**2)**. After I configured that setting, I could access `_snippetResult` in the function for the autocomplete.js library. As you can see in the image above, the attribute that I added to the 'Attributes to snippet' option was 'content', and so I access the words that matched with the search query with `suggestion._snippetResult.content.value`.

My code now is:

---

```
autocomplete('#search-input', { hint: true, autoselect: false }, [
{
    source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, { hitsPerPage: 7 }),
    displayKey: 'title',
    templates: {
        footer: '<span class="search-foot">Powered by <a href="https://www.algolia.com/" target="_blank" title="Algolia - Hosted cloud search as a service"><img src="/static/assets/algolia-logo.png" width="47" height="15"></a></span>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {

          return '<div class="search-lang">' + 
              suggestion._highlightResult.platform.value + 
              '</div><div class="search-title">' + 
              suggestion._highlightResult.title.value +
              '</div>' + '<div class="search-snippet">' + 
              suggestion._snippetResult.content.value + '</div>';
        }
    }
}
]).on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
  window.location.href = suggestion.url;
});
```

---

So to summarise, there is simply a manual option to enable the return of search snippets instead of having to use `attributesToSnippet` *somewhere* in the code.

Comment: Just for clarification, when you've set "Attributes to Snippet" in your dashboard, this just sets "attributesToSnippet" in your index settings behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

`attributesToIndex`, `attributesToHighlight` and `attributesToSnippet` are the three main [settings used for highlighting](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#highlighting--snippeting).

- [`attributesToIndex`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#attributestoindex) is an index setting (you can set it in your dashboard or your back-end, but not in the front-end).
- [`attributesToHighlight`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#attributestohighlight) are, if not set, equal to the `attributesToIndex`. They can be set in your index settings, as `attributesToIndex`, but can also be overridden at query time (and can only contain attributes also in `attributesToIndex`)
- [`attributesToSnippet`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#attributestosnippet) are, if not set, equal to an empty array. Each attribute can have a modifier at the end like `:10` to say how much words you want in your snippet. Other than that, they work the same way than `attributesToHighlight`.

Let's take an example:

*Index settings*

```
attributesToIndex: ['title', 'description']
attributesToHighlight: ['title']
attributesToSnippet: ['description:3']
```

*Record*

```
{
  "title": "Test article",
  "description": "A long long long test description long long long",
  "link": "https://test.com/test-article"
}
```

For the query `"test"`, here's basically the JSON of a suggestion you'd get:

```
{
  "title": "Test article",
  "description": "A long long long test description long long long",
  "link": "https://test.com/test-article",
  "_highlightResult": {
    "title": {
      "value": "<em>Test article</em>"
    }
  },
  "_snippetResult": {
    "description": {
      "value": "... long <em>test</em> description ..."
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that neither `description` nor `link` are in the `_highlightResult` object.
`link` was ignored from the search since it's not in the `attributesToIndex`
`description` is not in the `_highlightResult` because it's not in `attributesToHighlight`.

You can also notice that in both `_highlightResult` and `_snippetResult`, the `test` word is wrapped in `<em></em>` tags. That's the tags you can use to show which words matched.

I've omitted [some attributes of the answer](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/search#search-response-format) that didn't help understand my answer. You can see them in your browser console by adding a small `console.log(suggestion)` at the beginning of your suggestion function.

Comment: Thanks Jerska for your detailed answer. This did help me better understand the theory of the returned suggestions.