# How do I display my Wordpress custom field attribute in the excerpt of my Algolia Search page results?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, customization, algolia

I'm currently using Algolia's Search plugin within Worpdress.  I've managed to push some custom fields and their values to custom attributes within Algolia.  Now, I'm trying to include a custom attribute named 'program_description' in my search results.

By default, the search is only returning the value of the 'post_title' and 'content' attributes.  I'm interested in replacing the 'content' attribute output with with my custom attribute's output('program_description').

I thought I would simply modify the instantsearch.php template by adding 'program_description' to the attributes array like so:

```
<div class="ais-hits--content">
    <h3 itemprop="name headline"><a href="{{ data.permalink }}" title="{{ data.post_title }}" itemprop="url">{{{ data._highlightResult.post_title.value }}}</a></h3>
    <div class="ais-hits--tags">
        <# for (var index in data.taxonomies.post_tag) { #>
        <span class="ais-hits--tag">{{{ data._highlightResult.taxonomies.post_tag[index].value }}}</span>
        <# } #>
    </div>
    <div class="excerpt">
        <p>
            <#
            var attributes = ['program_description', 'content', 'title6', 'title5', 'title4', 'title3', 'title2', 'title1'];
            var attribute_name;
            var relevant_content = '';
            for ( var index in attributes ) {
                attribute_name = attributes[ index ];
                if ( data._highlightResult[ attribute_name ].matchedWords.length > 0 ) {
                    relevant_content = data._snippetResult[ attribute_name ].value;
                }
            }

            relevant_content = data._snippetResult[ attributes[ 0 ] ].value;
            #>
            {{{ relevant_content }}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In doing so, none of my results are returned and I'm met with the following console error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matchedWords' of undefined`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Cannot read property 'matchedWords' of undefined` tells me that your custom parameter for `attributes` may not be defined in the scope of Algolia.

I would suggest initializing [`attributesToIndex`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/parameters#attributestoindex) with your custom attributes (or any attributes you'll be using)- that way you can ensure that [`attributesToHighlight`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/parameters#attributestohighlight) has definitions to work with.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40044950/6836841)~ it might help shed light on why you're getting an `undefined` definition for your custom attribute while trying to access the `matchedWords` member of your `_highlightResult` object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm positive that the custom attribute is being indexed.  I can see it in the Algolia search dashboard.  Also, here is the output from the last API call which shows that 'program_description' has a snippet

Comment: @JimKulakowski - since the error is being thrown on a `matchedWords` attribute, it's clear that the problem lies within the definition of your `_highlightResult`- can you edit into your OP an output that shows the structure of the `_highlightResult` object?  Much like the test query provided within the answer I linked.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I'm not sure how to edit the output to include the _highlightResult object.  However, I did change my $settings to this:     $settings = array(
        'attributesToIndex' => array(
            'unordered(organisation_name)',
            'unordered(program_description)'
        ),
        'attributesToHighlight' => array(
            'unordered(organisation_name)',
            'unordered(program_description)'
        )
    );

Comment: I think I can also change those settings in the Algolia dashboard.  I guess I'm just confused on how I can pull those into my search results given the template that provided with the Algolia search plugin for Wordpress.

Comment: @JimKulakowski are you using the [`setSettings`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/getting-started#quick-start) function?  [This](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/search#search-in-an-index) part of the documentation gives example code that shows `_highlightResult` being returned with a query.  Sorry I can't really be of more help!

Comment: No Matt, I haven't messed with setSettings yet.  I assume this is being called somewhere within the WP plugin.  Thanks again for your help.  I'm going to continue to fumble through the documentation.

Comment: I'm essentially following this documentation on the Algoli WP plugin site: [https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/customize-search-page.html]

Comment: @JimKulakowski Have you tried taking out the extraneous indices of the `attributes` array?  The error might actually be thrown when it can't find a `content` or `title*` index.